# How to fix extra spacing when set minHeight?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

When i set container view with minHeight value when children grows it adds extra padding at bottom when container height is greater minHeight if i understood properly it should set minHeight when container size is less than minHeight but not when it's greater than minHeight and here is my code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        flexWrap: 'wrap',
                        justifyContent: 'space-between',
                        borderWidth: 1.5,
                        borderRadius: 8,
                        minHeight: 70,
                    }}
                />
                <View
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }}
                />
                <View
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue' }}
                />
                <View
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue' }}
                />
                <View style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                <View style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
                <View style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the gap between the view and the view?

Comment: @hongdevelop Yes there is additional gap at the end of children vertically even though parent height is more than minHeight(70 in this case) Please see here https://ibb.co/wBRRhdQ

Comment: Could you change value `height: 50` => `height:  "50%"` ?

Comment: It results in like this https://snack.expo.io/@teeolendo/min-height-error